# Adding Colorscheme to Neovim conditionally?

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, statusline

I'm trying to create a status line and get the color scheme correctly. I have the function

```
function GetDiagnosticErrorCount()
  local errorCount = #vim.diagnostic.get(0, { severity = vim.diagnostic.severity.ERROR })
  if (errorCount > 0) then
    return '  ' .. errorCount .. ''
  end
  return ''
end
```

and would like it to have a colorscheme. My current solution today is to add colorscheme before in the definition of the statusline.

```
%#StatusLineError#%{luaeval('GetDiagnosticErrorCount()')}%
```

However, this becomes bad because I don't want the space before the error count to get the highlight, and I don't want the space to be there unless it's needed. The ideal solution would be to be able to add the colorscheme directly in the returned string:

```
function GetDiagnosticErrorCount()
  local errorCount = #vim.diagnostic.get(0, { severity = vim.diagnostic.severity.ERROR })
  if (errorCount > 0) then
    return ' %#StatusLineError#% ' .. errorCount .. '%'
  end
  return ''
end
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Try using `%{%` as in `:help statusline` to re-evaluate the result as a statusline string? (If that works, feel free to self-answer.)

Answer (score 1):

As D. Ben Knoble suggested, you can wrap it in `%{% ... %}` and then it will be evaluated as a statusline string!